# How to use the matrix_keypad.h file for a custom keypad driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

can i emulate a custom keypad with input_dev (from input.h)

```
//an example with just one key.
button_dev = input_allocate_device();
    if (!button_dev) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "button.c: Not enough memory\n");
        error = -ENOMEM;
        goto err_free_irq;
    }

    button_dev->evbit[0] = BIT_MASK(EV_KEY);
    button_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_0)] = BIT_MASK(BTN_0);
```

or i will have to use matrix_keypad header file?If yes then How?

Comment: Yes, you can. See for example gpio_keys.c.

Comment: @0andriy, how do i know the platform data if i have to emulate it? What exactly is meant by "platform" in gpio_keys.c

Comment: @0andriy, I am reading about `struct matrix_keymap_data` and `struct matrix_keypad_platform_data`. how do i change the keymap according to the 4x4 keypad i am trying to emulate?